# SendGrid Asp.net controller

Tags: asp.net, axios, sendgrid

I have two controllers

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail([FromForm]string message) {
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync("mymail@somewhere.com", "Sending from contact", message.ToString());
            return Ok();
        }
```

And

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
        [Route("subscribe")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Subscribe( string recipient, [FromForm] string message)
        {
            var emailTemplate = "";
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(recipient, "Thank you for subscribing", message.ToString());
            return Ok();
        }
```

Now the first one works absolutely fine when I send an api cal using axios like this:

```
const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/SendGrid', `message=${emailContent}`)
```

Where emailContent is a whole html page template with variables inside it. And it works great!

When I try and use the second controller my api call is almost the same I just add the email of the user but for some reason it does not work.

```
const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/SendGrid/subscribe', `recipient=${values.subscribeEmail}&message=${SubscribedEmailTemplate()}` )
```

No idea why. What I need is a SendGrid controller that accepts an email and html template as variables and send them respectively.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Even more weird I keep getting NULL on the breakpoint for the reciepent. The message is there but the reciepent is null.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I cannot read more than one variable from body. So what I did was create a class and send the request as a json.

```
public class EmailData
    {
        public string Recipient { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
[HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
        [Route("subscribe")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Subscribe(EmailData emailData)
        {
            if (emailData.Recipient == null )
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var emailTemplate = "";
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(emailData.Recipient.ToString(), "Thank you for subscribing", emailData.Message.ToString());
            return Ok();
        }
```